# python list comprehension - learnpython.org

Tags: python, integer, list-comprehension

I have been working my way through the tutorials on learnpython.org and up to this point have found everything relatively straightforward.

When I came to the question about list comprehension I have become stuck. I have a grasp of how it works. Below is the question that is asked:

> Using a list comprehension, create a new list called "newlist" out of
>   the list "numbers", which contains only the positive numbers from the
>   list, as integers.

And the code supplied:

```
numbers = [34.6, -203.4, 44.9, 68.3, -12.2, 44.6, 12.7]
newlist = []

print newlist
```

My answer to this question was as follows:

```
newlist = [x for x in numbers if x > 0]
```

This returns the correct numbers from the array, but with each item to about 15 dp. How do I get just the integers and not all the decimal places.

For example that answer that is expected is:

> [34, 44, 68, 44, 12]

However I end up with:

> [34.600000000000001, 44.899999999999999, 68.299999999999997, 44.600000000000001, 12.699999999999999]

If anyone is able to shed some light as to where I am going wrong then it would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Jamie

Comment: Another victim!! **:D** http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/ (and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=weird+float+round+python ) Welcome to the club, though

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. It's like saying "print this list of floats as ints" without specifying whether you want rounding/truncation/etc. There are even different rules for different types of rounding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
newlist = [int(x) for x in numbers if x > 0]
```

This rounds numbers toward zero. Positive numbers will be rounded down and negative numbers will be rounded up. If you want to round to the nearest integer:

```
newlist = [round(x) for x in numbers if x > 0]
```

Comment: `int` doesn't rond to the next lower integer, `math.floor` does. `int`  rounds towards 0.

Comment: `round` still returns `float`. I would stick to the first version if the question doesn't specify how the conversion should be done

Comment: @Kos had a limit on how quick I could mark as right, thanks for the input